# Контроль интернет трафика

Tags: java, android

Как запретить своему приложению использовать мобильный интернет(3G,4G и т.д.) более заданного лимита(к примеру 1gb в месяц)?

Answer (score 1):

считать, сколько ваше приложение съело интернета с каждым запроссом, записывать это число куда-нибудь (`SharedPrefereces`?), и если оно превышает лимит - перестать отправлять запроссы.
Есть специальный класс [TrafficStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) для ваших целей. Еще можете посмотреть [NetworkStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html)

Comment: А как быть со сторонними АПИ(в моем случае Google maps)?
+ необходимо как то разграничивать WiFi трафик и мобильный.